# How to call bean method when drag-drop the element using <p:pickList>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using `primefaces 3.3` library for `jsf` based application.

I am using `<p:pickList>` to handle drag and drop the element from source to target and vide versa.

I want to call the `jsf` bean method when element transferring(by **drag-drop** ) from source to target and vice versa and handle some logical things there.

I follow the link [PrimeFaces showcase for pickList](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml) to implement my functionality. This is the version 5.2.7.

In **primefaces 5.2.7** it can be easily done by `<p:ajax event="transfer" />` , but how can I achieve this using **primafaces 3.3**.

I try **valueChangeListener** attribute but it is not working.
There is one attribute called **onTransfer** , but it is for clientSide callback.

This can be achieve by putting **submit** button. But I want to achieve it on drag and drop. So how can i do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should consider an update of your primefaces version. Updates are not only provided for new features but also for bug fixes, improvements (performance, stability) etc.

Currently I cannot find the documentation for 3.3, but what you could try is using `p:remoteCommand` (its in the 3.5 documentation, so maybe available):

use `onTransfer="submitToBean()"` along with a `p:remoteCommand` that might look like this:

```
<p:remoteCommand 
   name="submitToBean" 
   action="#{myBean.doSomething}"
   process="idOfYourPickList" 
   partialSubmit="true" />
```

Then the `onTransfer` Event will call the javascript method `submitToBean()` which in turn will process your picklist and call the action method.

Comment: Yes <p:remoteCommand> works well to call bean method from javascript even if I can send the data along with it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: And `<p:remoteCommand>` tag is available in [Primefaces 3.3 documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation).