# How to trigger JSF bean method on some JavaScript event, e.g. drop event

Tags: jsf, drag-and-drop

I would like to drag a list element `<li>` (f.ex) and drop it on a `<div>` (f.ex), then call a bean method. I can implement drag&drop functionality easily with Jquery for example, but I am not sure how to trigger the method call. I am using JSF 2.2 and not [primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944670/how-to-call-bean-method-when-drag-drop-the-element-using-ppicklist).

Comment: I have draggable LI elements that I can drop on divs, and the LI element is copied, so the DOM part is done. But I am not sure this should be done like this away from JSF. Then I don't know how to call the bean method once the element is copied on the div.

Comment: The solution provided works. I have a related difficulty that I forgot to comment, but it is probably a different question.